# query strings in Quick links modern webpart are not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I have added a modern quick links webpart on a sharepoint home page(modern) and given a link to site page with some query strings. when I tried to click on in it. Its navigating to a page the page but removing the query string parameters(in same window).

Comment: If you open a new browser window and paste the same url with querystring in the address bar, does it work?  Some sites/pages use the querystring for its own internal purposes and will automatically erase anything you try to type or paste in.  Can you share the url you are trying to use so we can reproduce?

Comment: its working, if I open it oother window. And the page which I am pointing is also site page in the same site(web part page)

Comment: What querystring value are you passing to a modern page?

Comment: Its not a modern page, its a classic page(web part page)

Comment: I think we are going to need more details, like which webparts are being used on the page, what querystring values you are trying to pass etc.  In general, querystring parameters are fully supported in the quicklinks webpart, and I have tested multiple scenarios, so the likely culprit exists in something specific in how you are linking or what you are linking to, I don't think anyone here can dig in deeper without additional specifics.

Comment: I have added a Modern Quick Links webpart on SharePoint Modern(group) site and given a link to Site Page which is a web part page which have script editor web part with some query string parameters like claim_id(i tested with other parameters also). once I click on the quick link its trying to redirect to site page but in url its removing all query strings in the same window. can you please give a try to